# Replacing Elements in 3 dimensional Python List

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I've a Python list if converted to NumPy array would have the following dimensions: (5, 47151, 10)

```
np.array(y_pred_list).shape 
# returns (5, 47151, 10)

len(y_pred_list)
# returns 5
```

I would like to go through every element and replace the element where:

- If the element >= 0.5 then 1.
- If the element < 0.5 then 0.

Any idea?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
arr=np.array(y_pred_list)  #list to narray
arr[arr<0.5]=0             #  arr<0.5 is a mask narray 
arr[arr>=0.5]=1
y_pred_list=arr.tolist()   # narray to list
```

Answer (score 1):

To create an array with a value True if the element is >= 0.5, and False otherwise:

```
new_array = y_pred_list >= 0.5
```

use the .astype() method for Numpy arrays to make all True elements 1 and all False elements 0:

```
new_array.astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

ibredeson's answer is the way to go in your specific case. When you have an array a and want to construct an array b of the same shape which takes only two values, depending on a condition on a, consider using `np.where` (see [the doc here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 1, 0.3, 0.5])
b = np.where(a > 0.5, 2, 7) # 2 and 7 are the values you want to see in b, whether the 
# corresponding element in a is lesser than 0.5 or not.
>>> b
array([7, 2, 7, 7])
```